# How to update global variables from browser with flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask

Using Flask, how to change global var contents from browser? Such that...

```
var = 1
@app.route('/', methods= ['GET', 'POST'])
def home_page():
    return '''
        <input type="number" name="var" />
        <form action="/next_page" method="post">
            <input type="submit" value = "go to next page"/>
        </form>''''
```

Where line after return'''--- will update var for every page visited?

Comment: so you want var to be incremented each time the form is submitted?

Comment: Maybe this is helpful for you - https://github.com/jugmac00/til/blob/master/flask/scope-of-data-persistency.md

Comment: Don't use global variables.

Comment: @AnaS Kayed, No. I'm storing whatever value is inputted by the user.

Comment: @J.G, thanks! This is a great lead.

Comment: Sure people with years of experience agree with me but because "Gavin Ray" a guy who just started with flask yesterday is declaring that global variables are good, then they are.

Comment: Haha @Patch, I hear ya. Maybe all these awesome people you know could get together and give me a better response than 'Don't use global variables'. Answers like that leave people with no direction. Ok, so I won't use global variables in this situation; what should I do instead?

Comment: You can Google it pretty easily. https://amp-reddit-com.cdn.ampproject.org/v/s/amp.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/3mnw8w/are_global_variables_thread_safe_in_flask/?amp_js_v=a3&amp_gsa=1&usqp=mq331AQIKAGwASDAAQE%3D#aoh=15994144765553&csi=1&referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com&amp_tf=From%20%251%24s&ampshare=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.reddit.com%2Fr%2Flearnpython%2Fcomments%2F3mnw8w%2Fare_global_variables_thread_safe_in_flask%2F https://stackabuse.com/local-and-global-variables-in-python/ you can Google it and see more if you'd like

Answer (score 0):

In the following code, I changed the action of the form to the same view, and in the view I check if the request method is GET or POST.

```
@app.route('/', methods= ['GET', 'POST'])
def home_page():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return '''
            <html>
            <head><title>Title</title></head>
            <body>
                <form action="/" method="post">
                    <input type="number" name="var" />
                    <input type="submit" value = "go to next page"/>
                </form>
            </body>
            </html>
            '''
    else:
        number = request.form.get('var')
        global var
        var = number
        print(var)
        return 'Done'
```

In your code, you placed the input outside the form, so it won't be submitted with the form, so I placed it inside. After you submit the form with the new *var* you want, it will change it globally, and to make sure, I'm printing the global variable *var*